# Finding html of a jquery file

Tags: jquery, html

I have three big problems, for which I have opened two topics already. This is my last issue, which is very easy for people like you, but certainly not easy for people like me (I have no idea of jquery or whatsoever)...

So, this is the problem: I have a (working?) script, but I can't use it because I don't have the HTML code of it. Could you please help me out by giving this code? Thanks in advance lads!

FYI: this is a downloaded script called "Modalpreview', but it has no HTML file in the downloaded folder.

```
            (function($){

var $defaults = {
    fade:      'fast',
    allowHtml: false,
    opacity:   '0.7',
    text:      {
        preview: 'Preview',
        close:   'Close'
    }
};

var $o = $.extend($defaults, $options);

var _o = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
    display: 'none',
    opacity: $o.opacity
}).attr('id','overlay');

$('body').append(_o);

return this.each(function(){

    var _c = $(this);
    var _f = $(this).parents('form');
    var _b = _f.find('input[type=submit]');
    var _t = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('preview_txt');
    var _h = $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('preview_header').text($o.text.preview+':');
    var _k = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('preview_inputwrapper');
    var _d = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('preview_div').css({
                display:'none'
             });
    var _p = $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
                 value:$o.text.preview,
                 type: 'button'
             }).addClass('preview_btn');
    /*
    var _s = _b.clone(true).click(function() {
        _f.find('*[name=submit]').attr('name','_submit');
        _f.submit();
    });
    */
    var _e = $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
                 value:$o.text.close,
                 type: 'button'
             }).addClass('edit_btn');
    _k.append(_e);
    _d.append(_h).append(_t).append(_k);
    _o.after(_d);
    _p.click(function() {
        if (_c.val().length < 1) {
            return;
        }
        _o.fadeIn($o.fade);
        var _i = (!$o.allowHtml) ? $$.removeTags(_c.val()) : _c.val();
        _t.html($$.parse(_i));
        _e.click(function() {
            _o.fadeOut($o.fade);
            _d.fadeOut($o.fade,function() { _t.empty(); });
            _c.focus();
        });
        _d.fadeIn($o.fade);
    });
    _b.before(_p);
});
```

Comment: Two words. **Inspect. Element.**

Comment: I have tried every possible way, I couldn't find it. If I had, I wouldn't ask. I hope that here are people who can and will help me.

Comment: What do you mean "but I can't use it because I don't have the HTML code "? Where did you get the jquery from? Whoever or wherever you got this from should have doc's for you to use it. Try that first.

Comment: If you are using IE you need to hit the refresh button in the developer tools (the one looks like a arrows in a circle not the browser refresh) before you can inspect anything.

Comment: Does the demo page have any html?  ;)

Comment: There's no HTML file because the jQuery plugin writes whatever HTML it needs dynamically!

Comment: So, you found a jQuery plugin, and want us to give you HTML that goes with it?  Where did you find this plugin?  Did you try running it?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't actually do anything.  It makes a function, but is never ran.

Comment: @Sparky672: It looks like it's supposed to be a jquery plugin (`$.fn`), because of the `return this.each`, but it starts with `(function($){`, so something's not right here.

Comment: It has no demo page. Google for Modalpreview and you can find everywhere the same file to download, which contains none html file.

Beside that, it is a complete file, but I edited a bit, because it didn't fit in here.

Comment: @user1627363: I found a link to it (http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Modal-Windows/Modalpreview-61456.html), and you are missing a major part of the script.

Comment: Then switch to a more up-to-date and complete plugin.  This one has no documentation and was written more than 2 years ago.

Comment: I am missing a major part of the script, because it didn't fit in here. Beside that, the part I have given is enough to output the HTML code, that I do know.

@Sparky: there is no up-to-date modalbox script which gets the textarea's text.

Comment: You admitted to _"no idea of jquery or whatsoever"_, but somehow you know there is no other suitable plugin?

Comment: @user1627363: You are supposed to make a `textarea` and then call this plugin on it: `$('textarea').modalpreview({options});`

Comment: @Sparky: There is no other suitable plugin. You can believe me. I have no idea of Jquery code, yes, but I do know something about HTML etc. Please, don't react anymore if  you can't help me.

Comment: @user1627363: I'm sure there are plenty of suitable plugins.  What is this one supposed to do?

Comment: @Rocket: Yes, I do know that, but how do I do that exactly?

I have tried a div in which I added a textarea, but how do I let the jquery script do the work?

Comment: @user1627363: What do you mean?

Comment: It is a PREVIEW of the TEXTAREA text. Other plugins are mostly pop-ups *which can't be styled*. This is the only MODALBOX plugin I could find.

Comment: My comments are designed to get to the root of this communication breakdown.  You can't be too picky about who tries to help you.

Comment: I suggest reading the comments in the plugin, they should tell you how to use it.

Comment: I have done that already...
I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @user1627363: Can you post what you've tried to do to get it working?

Comment: <div class="preview_txt"><textarea class="preview_div"></textarea><input type="submit" onclick=fn.modalpreview()"></div>

Is one of the things I tried. And many many other variants.

Answer (score 2):

After downloading the plugin (from: [here](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Modal-Windows/Modalpreview-61456.html) [download from Softpedia's mirror, the plugin's homepage no longer has it]), I figured out how to use it.

Your text area needs to be in a `form`, and that `form` needs to have a `submit` button.

So, the "missing HTML" should be:

```
<form>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
<form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And then the jQuery to enable this is:

```
$('form textarea').modalpreview();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/TqTXA/

Comment: I can't give you a vote up, but you certainly deserved it! Thank you very much!

@Robin: good luck finding another plugin like this. I wonder how long you will be searching.

Comment: @user1627363: Personally, if I can't find a good plugin in a few minutes, I'll just make my own.

Comment: Yes, then you have to be good at things I am not. If I could, I had done it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browser you're using -

1. [right-click and "Inspect Element"](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) for chrome.
2. [Developer tools](https://superuser.com/questions/43653/whats-ie8-equivalent-of-chrome-and-firefox-firebug-inspect-element) for IE.
3. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads) for FF.
4. There's also [FirebugLite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) for every other(modern) browser.

Comment: Oh god... Search for it I'd say... It is a jquery modalbox called "Modalpreview", but there is no html code. In the downloaded folder there is a CSS file with 3 Jquery files, but no HTML. That's why I am asking you this. Firebug, right-clicking etc. are the most obvious things to do. Jquery ist just not my thing, that's all.

Comment: @user1627363: You didn't mention that in your question you see. "modalpreview"? download? Try adding that to your question mate. Sorry for the trivial answers, but you can't blame me (the reader) really.

Comment: Alright, that's my fault then. I had to be precise. 

Now then, I hope someone can solve this.

Comment: @user1627363, Solve what exactly?  The plugin uses jQuery to write its own HTML dynamically.  Now please edit your question to describe the actual problem you're having.

Comment: I am quoting: 

"So, this is the problem: I have a (working?) script, but I can't use it because I don't have the HTML code of it. Could you please help me out by giving this code?"

I need the HTML code so that I can click on it and open the modalbox.

Comment: @user1627363: You say its working? So then it should generate its own HTML. But you don't have it. You say you already know about inspection tools. What then?

Comment: @user1627363, You'll need to go find and look at the demo page for the plugin.

Comment: There is NO DEMO PAGE. That was the obvious thing to do, but there isn't a demo page.

Comment: @user1627363: Calm down. I give up. But I have upvoted your question.

Comment: @RobinMaben... Yes, the code is complete and it has to work, but there is no HTML to output in the code. I have to CLICK something, right? Yes, so I have to get the code in which the jquery code is fetched and the textarea's text is printed on the modalbox.

Comment: @user1627363: Seems like its time to find another modal box plugin. There's soo many out there! Just saying. ;)

Comment: There is no other modal box plugin which fetches the text of the textarea and previews it. Alright Robin, show me when you find one :)

Comment: @user1627363: Aah. Finally you have arrived at the real question my friend.

Comment: Well then, I am waiting for your submission ;)